# Conditionaly move certain posts at the bottom of the query result

Tags: wp-query, order

How can I move certain posts returned by WP_Query to the bottom of the results?

I am using this method..

```
$exp_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'apartment',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);
$exp_query = new WP_Query( $exp_args );

if ( $exp_query->have_posts() ) {                               

    foreach( $exp_query->posts as $key => $result ) {
        $bb24rrid = get_post_meta( $result->ID, '_b24_room_id', true);
        if ( isset($apiresults[$bb24rrid]['minstay'] ) ) {
            $item = $exp_query->posts[$key];
            unset($exp_query->posts[$key]);
            array_push($exp_query->posts, $item);
        }
    }
    
    while ( $exp_query->have_posts() ) {
        $exp_query->the_post();
        //Loop Codes Here..
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

This doesn't work. Evenif I remove `array_push` it's still showing the post.

The `$apiresults` is ann external array of `_b24_room_id` meta field values. I have to compare if the `$apiresults[$bb24rrid]['minstay']` is set then push the post at the bottom.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for fixing the issue in question, you should first always check that `$apiresults[$bb24rrid]` is set, i.e. exists, and secondly, you should create an array which stores the posts that should go at the bottom and then merge it with the `$exp_query->posts` array, instead of pushing items in the `foreach` loop.

```php
// Array of posts (WP_Post objects) which should go at the bottom.
$bottom_posts = array();

foreach( $exp_query->posts as $key => $result ) {
    $bb24rrid = get_post_meta( $result->ID, '_b24_room_id', true);
    if ( isset( $apiresults[$bb24rrid] ) &&
        is_array( $apiresults[$bb24rrid] ) &&
        isset( $apiresults[$bb24rrid]['minstay'] )
    ) {
        $bottom_posts[] = $exp_query->posts[$key];
        unset($exp_query->posts[$key]);
    }
}

$exp_query->posts = array_merge( $exp_query->posts, $bottom_posts );
```

The other possible way to achieve your goal is by using 2 `while ( $exp_query->have_posts() )` loops like so, where the first one excludes the posts that should go at the bottom, and the second loop displays *only* those excluded posts. This approach is best used with a template part, to avoid duplicating codes in the loops.

```php
// Array of posts (IDs) which should go at the bottom.
$bottom_posts = array();

while ( $exp_query->have_posts() ) {
    $exp_query->the_post();

    $post_id  = get_the_ID();
    $bb24rrid = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_b24_room_id', true );

    if ( isset( $apiresults[$bb24rrid] ) &&
        is_array( $apiresults[$bb24rrid] ) &&
        isset( $apiresults[$bb24rrid]['minstay'] )
    ) {
        $bottom_posts[] = $post_id;
        continue;
    }

    get_template_part( 'your-template-part' );
}

while ( $exp_query->have_posts() ) {
    $exp_query->the_post();

    if ( ! in_array( get_the_ID(), $bottom_posts ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    get_template_part( 'your-template-part' );
}
```

Or you could instead use `$bottom_posts[] = get_post();` and then replace the 2nd loop above with:

```php
global $post;
foreach ( $bottom_posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );
    get_template_part( 'your-template-part' );
}
```

**Additional Notes**

1. I believe it's more performant if you remove the `'orderby' => 'rand'` and then randomize the posts via PHP, e.g. do a `shuffle( $exp_query->posts );` right after the `new WP_Query()` call.
2. `'posts_per_page' => -1` (which disables pagination or enables a "no LIMIT" query) should be avoided, and instead, use a number which you know would never be reached, e.g. if the query would only ever return at most 60 posts, then use `'posts_per_page' => 60`. (If you're thinking about using 999 or another high number, though, then you should better off use pagination, e.g. 30 posts per page.)